# How can I show the most recent date associated with an entity when the dates are stored in a separate table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables, one is a list of concerts and each one has an ID and a date. The other tables is a list of songs and the concert ID where they were played. Songs may appear multiple times in that table, and I want to be able to display the most recent time each song was played (in a list).

Concerts Table:

```
Concert_ID     Date   
-------------------------
c1             1/1/2014
c2             1/2/2014
c3             1/3/2014
```

Songs Tables:

```
Song_ID    Concert_ID      
-------------------------
s1         c1
s2         c1
s1         c2
s3         c2
s2         c3
```

Desired Results:

```
Song_ID    Date      
-------------------------
s1         1/2/2014
s2         1/3/2014
s3         1/2/2014
```

Comment: What is the datatype of date column?

Comment: The datatype for the date column is 'DATE'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `date` column in concerts table is of date type, you can join the two tables like this:

```
select s.song_id, max(c.date)
from songs s
inner join concerts c
on s.concert_id = c.concert_id
group by s.song_id;
```

if the column is not of date type, use `str_to_date(c.date, '%m/%d/%Y')` instead of `c.date`.

---

```
create table concerts(Concert_ID varchar(100), Dt date);
insert into concerts values ('c1',str_to_date('1/1/2014','%m/%d/%Y'));
insert into concerts values ('c2',str_to_date('1/2/2014','%m/%d/%Y'));
insert into concerts values ('c3',str_to_date('1/3/2014','%m/%d/%Y'));

create table songs (Song_ID varchar(100), Concert_ID varchar(100));
insert into songs values ('s1','c1');
insert into songs values ('s2','c1');
insert into songs values ('s1','c2');
insert into songs values ('s3','c2');
insert into songs values ('s2','c3');

select s.song_id, max(c.dt)
from songs s
inner join concerts c
on s.concert_id = c.concert_id
group by s.song_id;
```

Produces:

```
+---------+------------+
| song_id | max(c.dt)  |
+---------+------------+
| s1      | 2014-01-02 |
+---------+------------+
| s2      | 2014-01-03 |
+---------+------------+
| s3      | 2014-01-02 |
+---------+------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, but when adding 'max()' to the date select statement the dates no longer appear. When I remove 'max ()' then the _least_ recent date shows.
The column is indeed of date type.

Comment: dates no longer appear meaning? you get null?

Comment: Correct, I get null

Comment: I've just now tested it and it works without any issues. I've updated my answer too.

Comment: Ah, I figured out the issue. I needed to select _max(c.date) AS date_. This works perfectly now. Thank you so much!